# PLSQL DEFINE variable populate using cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need some help with dynamic SQL and cursor.
I have stored procedure which has DEFINE variables.
How I can populate DEFINE variable using cursor?

I want to use another table as source for cursor and insert these results to another table.

Here is simplified example about my problem:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE usp_TEST
AS
BEGIN

DEFINE vTable = 'TABLE_NAME'; -- How I can create cursor loop, so I can loop and change this table name using another table as source?


INSERT INTO results
WITH CTE_main
AS
(
    SELECT 
        TABLE_NAME 
    FROM dest_TABLES
)
SELECT 
    'SELECT * FROM ' || '&vTable' || ' source INNER JOIN ' ||  cte.TABLE_NAME || ' dest ON source.ID = dest.ID;' AS query 
FROM CTE_main cte

END;
```

Source table contains only table names:

TABLE_ONE

TABLE_TWO

etc...

Result should be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_ONE source INNER JOIN DEST_ONE dest ON source.ID = dest.ID;
SELECT * FROM TABLE_ONE source INNER JOIN DEST_TWO dest ON source.ID = dest.ID;
SELECT * FROM TABLE_TWO source INNER JOIN DEST_ONE dest ON source.ID = dest.ID;
SELECT * FROM TABLE_TWO source INNER JOIN DEST_TWO dest ON source.ID = dest.ID;
```

Comment: Your requirement is confusing. How are you planning to pass tables `TABLE_ONE`, `TABLE_TWO`  etc? `DEFINE` can't  be used in PL/SQL.

Comment: Well... That's the problem... I need to execute procedure multiple times and every time with different value in DEFINE varible. But you're saying it impossible to create loop around DEFINE variable and run it multiple times?

Comment: It can be done, but not as a PL/SQL variable.But, the question is why do you wan't to do it this way.We may be able to provide you  with  better solutions to your final problem if you explain a bit more what you actually want.

Comment: The PL/SQL language has no 'define' keyword, and the `&` symbol has no special meaning. It does have variables and procedure parameters though, so perhaps those are what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Are you after something like:

```
WITH dest_tables AS (SELECT 'TABLE_ONE' table_name FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 'TABLE_TWO' table_name FROM dual),
        cte_main AS (SELECT 'DEST_ONE' table_name FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 'DEST_TWO' table_name FROM dual)
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM ' || dt.table_name || ' src INNER JOIN ' ||  cm.TABLE_NAME || ' dest ON src.ID = dest.ID;' AS query 
FROM   dest_tables dt
       CROSS JOIN cte_main cm
ORDER BY dt.table_name, cm.table_name;

QUERY
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT * FROM TABLE_ONE src INNER JOIN DEST_ONE dest ON src.ID = dest.ID;
SELECT * FROM TABLE_ONE src INNER JOIN DEST_TWO dest ON src.ID = dest.ID;
SELECT * FROM TABLE_TWO src INNER JOIN DEST_ONE dest ON src.ID = dest.ID;
SELECT * FROM TABLE_TWO src INNER JOIN DEST_TWO dest ON src.ID = dest.ID;
```

? (N.B. I used the two subqueries in the with-clause to mimic data in your tables; you wouldn't need those two subqueries, you'd just use your tables instead.)

No PL/SQL is required, just SQL. You could take the above statement and use it in an insert statement inside a PL/SQL program, though.